# Where is the correct place to put find functions?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that is split into several smaller Java Projects. I have this Account object that stores user credentials, etc. I want to create a function to return all characters that account has, e.g. findCharacters(); Where should I put that, inside an API or in the Account class itself?

Comment: Any where you like, there are no rules.

Comment: Well... it depends™

Comment: I would put it inside the Account class. Because it is a part of it. But I wouldn't call it findCharacters but something like 'getCharacters()'. Because you don't get specific one(s).

Comment: What sort of characters are you talking about? Do you mean characters as in those taking part in a play, or characters like letters and numbers? Why would an Account class have any characters?

Answer (score 0):

It is better place that function inside Account class as it is related functionality to Account object.

```
public class Account {
   //properties go here


   int findCharacters() {
   //method logic goes here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Java, I recommend using its Object Oriented nature and capabilities. Oracle has a decent tutorial on Java and OOP. Here are some references to get you started:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/
2. http://people.ucls.uchicago.edu/~bfranke/apcs_0809/downloads/BPJ_TextBook_3_0_5.pdf

Just go for the function: findCharacters() inside the Account class.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say: it *depends*.

From a pure OO point of view, the first place to look for would be the `Account` class itself.

But the important thing is: the `Account` should follow the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles - namely: single responsibility! Therefore one has to be careful to *only* have those methods inside a class that contribute to that *single responsibility*. In other words: you want to *avoid* adding all kinds of methods on a specific class - just because that method is *mainly* using objects of that class.

Domain Driven Design gives a hint what to do when the method "doesn't fit" into the "domain object": you turn to special [service](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) classes to wrap around that "service like" functionality.

Which model to pick/follow depends on the context of your application.